# test with firebase database throwing error

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-espresso

I'm using firebase in my project and i'm testing all the functionalities which includes firebase components and i recently tried to test firebase database but it is throwing an error which i could not understand if someone could help , i would appreciate it , Thank you

- error that i'm getting

```
  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.revert.journey.app.chatui.ChatHomeActivityTest.testCaseSendMessage
```

- This is my testing code

```
  @Test
    fun testCaseSendMessage(){
        val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)
        ServiceLocator.reference = databaseMock
        `when`(databaseMock.child("Messages").child("1251515").setValue(Utils.message()))
            .thenReturn(isNotNull())

    }
```

- This is my real code

```
    val messageMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
        messageMap["userName"] = userName
        messageMap["userMessage"] = message
        messageMap["userPic"] = userPic
        messageMap["messageTiming"] = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis.toString()
        messageMap["chatImage"] = downloadUrl
        messageMap["uid"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid

        ServiceLocator.reference
            .child("Messages")
            .child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            .setValue(messageMap).await()
```

- ServiceLocator class

```
object ServiceLocator {

    var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

}
```

- Image Sample from my firebase

[image]

- UPDATE

```
 var base = ServiceLocator.reference.child("Messages")
 var child = base.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
 child.setValue(messageMap).await()
```

Comment: What is the error? Your millisecond time probably doesn't match your mocked value of "1251515", may want to use `anyString()` there instead

Comment: I'm getting an error that database is invoked with nullpointerexception , i have included the error and service locator class as well , Thank you

Comment: I am guessing `System.currentTimeMillis().toString()` does not equal `1251515`, so the mock isn't applied and the methods return null. Try changing your mock to use `anyString()` instead of `"1251515"`

Comment: i did write anyString() instead and it still shows the same error weird

Comment: Ok, next step would be to break the call chain up into individual pieces so you can figure out which one is null (`val c1 = ServiceLocator.reference.child("Messages")` `val c2 = c1.child(...)` `val t = c2.setValue(...)` `t.await()` etc). Maybe try mocking the intermediate state too (`doReturn(databaseChild).when(databaseMock).child(anyString())`)

Comment: Set up the individual mocks like `doReturn(databaseChild).when(databaseMock).child(anyString())` so that calls like that do not return null. And edit your question to show what you have tried rather than in a comment please. All of these are because of missing mocks, which wouldn't affect how it works in production.

Comment: It still does not work but i have included the update in my code , please check it out and see if it is fine , Thank you , it still points to the line of child("Messages")

Comment: I meant to break those calls up in your real code, not in the test... I will attempt an answer...

Comment: I have made a new update by breaking my real code

Comment: You are right , breaking the production code into pieces made the test work , Thank you so much mate , but what is the clue that it does not work not broken into pieces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Mock the full call chain you could create mocks for the intermediate states like this (I don't know all the right types to use here for realtime database, but a similar approach works for Firestore)

```kotlin
val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)
val childMock = mock(Reference::class.java)
val mockTask = mock(??) // set type to whatever "setValue" returns

doReturn(childMock).`when`(databaseMock).child(anyString())
doReturn(childMock).`when`(childMock).child(anyString())
doReturn(mockTask).`when`(childMock).setValue(any())
```

If you want to actually test that the correct value was set, you can add a listener to the mock to intercept the actual value passed to it

```kotlin
doAnswer { invocation ->
    val args = invocation.arguments
    val l = args[0] as Map<String,Any>
    //add tests here to assert that the map values you sent are correct
    null
}.`when`(childMock).setValue(any())
```

**Debugging Tips**

If you want to diagnose what is going on in a scenario like this you can change the chained call in your real code to something like the code below. Then if one of the calls returns null you will know exactly which one it is and can add the missing mock for it.

```kotlin
val db = ServiceLocator.reference
val cm = db.child("Messages")
val ct = cm.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
val response = ct.setValue(messageMap)
response.await()
```

None of these call should access your database in the test, so the actual database schema does not matter. All that matters is getting the mocks set correctly (since you are using a mock database anyway)

Comment: it worked by breaking the code into pieces , Thank you so much

Comment: @Taki Glad it worked