# getting error mocking firebase user with mockito

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to mock a firebase user to provide it for my test , i have mocked the firebase auth class from which i get the uid of the currently signed in user but for some it keeps throwing the same error , i would appreciate your helps guys

- This is my production code

```
    private fun getUserProfileInfo(){
        val db = ServiceLocator.reference
        val child = db.child("Users")
        val user = ServiceLocator.firebaseUser
        val value = child.child(user!!.uid)

           value.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object  : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        val model = snapshot.getValue(ProfileModel::class.java)
                        userName = model!!.firstName
                        userPic = model.profilePicUrl
                    }
                }
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                }

            })
    }
```

- This is my testing code

```
  @Test
    fun testCaseProfileInfo(){
        val firebaseUserMock = mock(FirebaseUser::class.java)
        val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
        val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)

        ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth = firebaseMock
        ServiceLocator.firebaseUser = firebaseUserMock
        ServiceLocator.reference = databaseMock

        doReturn(firebaseUserMock).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
        val uid = doReturn("123").`when`(firebaseMock).uid // error here

        doReturn(databaseMock.child("Users")
            .child(uid!!))
            .`when`(databaseMock).get()
    }
```

- This is my Service Locator Class

```
object ServiceLocator {
    var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Utils.DATABASE_URL).reference
}
```

- Error generated ( after update )

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.revert.journey.app.chatui.FriendsRequestActivityTest.testCaseProfileInfo
```

- Quick Update

```
 @Test
    fun testCaseProfileInfo(){
        val userMock = mock(FirebaseUser::class.java)
        val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
        val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)

        ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth = firebaseMock
        ServiceLocator.firebaseUser = userMock
        ServiceLocator.reference = databaseMock

        doReturn(userMock).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
        doReturn("123").`when`(userMock)!!.uid

        doReturn(databaseMock
            .child("Users")
            .child("123")) //  ( null pointer exception on this string)..
            .`when`(databaseMock).get()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to mock the returned user from FirebaseAuth as well, something like this

```
val userMock = mock(FirebaseUser::class.java)

doReturn(userMock).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
doReturn("123").`when`(userMock).uid
```

If you split out your production code into a few more steps (like this), you would probably see that `currentUser` is null

```
val db = ServiceLocator.reference
val child = db.child("Users")
val user = ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth.currentUser
val uid = user?.uid ?: return
val value = child.child(uid)
```

The important thing to remember with mocked classes is that *all* their methods will return null unless you specifically set a return for them.

For a complete mock of the calls above, you would need the following mocks

If you want your method to be callable, you would need the following mocks. Your test method *is not interacting with Firebase at all* - it is a fake class (a mock) so you have to specifically tell it what to return when you call methods or get attributes from it. Your goal for testing is to define those return values in such a way as to get some useful operation from your method you can test.

```
@Test
 fun testCaseProfileInfo(){
    val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
    val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)
    val userMock = mock(FirebaseUser::class.java)
    val childMock = mock(Reference::class.java)
    
    ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth = firebaseMock
    ServiceLocator.reference = databaseMock
    
    
    // Tell the firebaseMock what to return when 
    // you call "currentUser"
    doReturn(userMock).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
    
    // Tell "userMock" to return "123" when you call
    // currentUser.uid in your production method
    doReturn("123").`when`(userMock).uid
    
    // Tell the database mock what to return when
    // you call db.child("Users")
    doReturn(childMock).`when`(databaseMock).child("Users")
    
    // Tell the users mock what to return when you
    // call db.child(uid)
    doReturn(childMock).`when`.usersMock("123")
    
    // Method should now be callable, but adding a listener for the event would be good to test
}
```

For a more complete example, consider the following method to get the user id if they are logged in, that you would like to test with mocks.

```kotlin
fun getUID(): String? {
    val uid = ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid
    return uid
}
```

You could write tests for this as follows

```kotlin
@Test
fun testUserNotLoggedIn(){
    val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
    
    ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth = firebaseMock
    doReturn(null).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
    
    assertNull(getUID())
}
```

```kotlin
@Test
fun testUserLoggedIn(){
    val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
    val userMock = mock(FirebaseUser::class.java)
    
    ServiceLocator.firebaseAuth = firebaseMock
    doReturn(userMock).`when`(firebaseMock).currentUser
    doReturn("123").`when`(userMock).uid
    
    assertEqual("123", getUID())
}
```

Comment: It can return whatever you want your mock auth to say the `uid` is for testing. You have to understand, your mock is not interacting with Firebase at all, it just returns what you tell it to. The values you use have no relation to what is in the actual database. You need to design your test around this (e.g. if you have some method that determines if the user is logged in, you could have it return null for the uid and verify that the method returns false, then have it return some uid-looking string and check that the method returns true).

Comment: Maybe you should post your whole test (in the question, not here) - the test you posted doesn't actually check anything (there are no assertions, no checks that the values return). It doesn't check any sort of correctness as-written.

Comment: Please post the updated code to the question

Comment: `val uid = doReturn("123").when(firebaseMock).uid` is not valid, a `doReturn` doesn't return anything. Remove the `val uid =` from it... I'll add some updates to the answer

Comment: I added more details. Basically when you say `doReturn("123")` you are telling the mock to return the string "123" in the production code when it asks for the uid. Your mocks should then expect to get a user id of "123" and act accordingly

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Please carefully read my answer and if you have separate questions, ask a separate question. You never mocked the `db.child("Users")` call, so that returns null, then you try to call `child("123")` on that and it will fail with a NPE. You have a to mock **every** method you call. Your last `doReturn` call appears pointless given the code you have posted anyway, it doesn't make sense to return a call chain like that.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are actually testing, or what you are trying to do. There's not much more I can say that I haven't already said. Maybe you should try posting a complete example and describing what you are actually trying to test. In what you posted you never even call the method in test, nor is there any "get()" call to be seen.

Comment: There is a "get()" in your **test** code, I don't see one anywhere in the production code you are trying to test. You also never call the production code in your test at all, so this is either incomplete or not actually testing anything. This chain has gone on long enough though, I can't help you further unless you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Yeah, you still have to actually call your production code somewhere. Look at the test example in my answer (defined mocks, then calls `getUID()` to test it using those mocks). All you are doing is defining mocks. You can add some print statements in your production code to check.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - if you want to test your production code you have to actually call methods from the production code. Just defining mocks doesn't call the production code.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718019/test-with-firebase-database-throwing-error/70724377#70724377), you would have to intercept the callback (using `doAnswer`), then call its methods with test data. Please, ask a new specific question if you have one - the comments on Stackoverflow are not meant as an interactive chat.

Comment: Hey mate , are you familiar with testing coroutines flow , i have opened a new topic if you can help , Thank you , this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900883/error-while-test-viewmodel-and-coroutine-flow